# XPath one of multiple elements of an attribute

Tags: xpath, scrapy

in this HTML using `scrapy` i can access the full `info-car` by : `'.//@info-car'` XPath

```
<div class="car car-root"
     info-car='{brand&quot;:&quot;BMW&quot;,&quot;Price&quot;:&quot;&#30000&quot;name&quot;:&quot;X5&quot;,&quot;color&quot;:null,&quot;}'>
</div>
```

what is the XPath to pick only the `name` of `info-car` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can obtain the name by using a combination of `xpath` and `regex`. See below sample code:

```py
response.xpath(".//@info-car").re_first(r'"name":"(.*)",')
```

Comment: thanks for answer , the output is like: 'X5","color":' it will read string until the last find of ", instead of first find of ", and its ok with limiting the end .re_first(r'"name":"(.*)","color')   ,may i ask if possible to extract all the field elements paired ?i'm using scrapy crawl cars -O cars.json